# Parallel copy from one source to multiple destinations simultaneously

Tags: linux, windows, file-transfer

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Multiple USB HDD (ext2 ) copy simultaneously](https://superuser.com/questions/81280/multiple-usb-hdd-ext2-copy-simultaneously)
>   [Parallel file copy from single source to multiple targets?](https://superuser.com/questions/32630/parallel-file-copy-from-single-source-to-multiple-targets)

Is any program (Linux /Windows) can copy large data (60 - 80 GB) to multiple drives simultaneously. It should do parallel copy from one source to multiple destinations of local disks(not for network disks using multicast).

Comment: you've already asked this question: http://superuser.com/questions/81280/multiple-usb-hdd-ext2-copy-simultaneously ... looks like you have two accounts ( http://superuser.com/users/20976/linuxnewbie and http://superuser.com/users/20839/linuxnewbie ); you should email team@superuser and request they merge the old account so you can update and your original question.

Comment: And a third: http://superuser.com/users/21334/linuxnewbie Also PLEASE read the FAQ (given your "answer" which should have been a comment at the earlier question). Thanks & success.

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you can use tee from the command line to copy to multiple destinations.

```
cat file | tee outfile1 outfile2
```

You can use `cp` along with `xargs` to copy entire folders to multiple destinations:

```
echo somedir somedir2 | xargs -n 1 cp -a folder/
```

On Windows, there is [n2ncopy](http://www.jose.hostse.com/misproyectos/n2ncopyen.zip):

[image]