# is there are way to do parallel copy with xargs or parallel but maintain the folder structure?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash

I try to implement parallel copy in bash to increase the throughput.

```
find <src> -type f -print0 | shuf -z | xargs -0 -P8 -n50 cp --parents  -t <dest>
```

above command does not work because there is racing that some parents dir is already created by other cp processes. I wonder is there a way to pass something like `--exists-ok` to let the cp command ignore the existing parents.

Or maybe there is other existing tool can already do this?

All the already answered questions^[1](https://superuser.com/questions/327659/whats-the-best-way-to-perform-a-parallel-copy-on-unix)^ from other places do not handle `--parents` that means, they only good for files in single dir level.

several alternative that does not really work:

find all dirs instead of all the files, then mkdir first and `cp *` in the dir. This approach resolve the error. But it missed the point of increasing copy throughput. Because some of the dirs has far more files than others:

```
find $src -type d -links 2 -print0 | shuf -z | xargs -0 -P8 -I{} bash -c "mkdir {}; cp -R {} $dest/"
```

If 1 or 2 dir has lots of files then, I end up runing 1 or 2 processes for very long at the end.

Of course I can again fork more copy in each dir. However, this blows up the process number and when lots of dirs only contain small amount of files then I end up spawn lots of cp processes. This slows things down too.

### cannot be done

I give a second thought about this, it won't work at all. It is not because the cp cannot ignore the existing dirs, another tool cpio can do this. However, there is a racing to create dir in each processes. 2 processes can start to create a same parent dir when both of them see there is no dir at all. The dir creating thus need to be in a single thread before all files can be written to it.

Comment: actually multithreads/multiprocesses copy are always a choice when there are many files.

Comment: @FrankThomas performance wise it probably does not make any sense to parallelize it. but for benchmark or simulation I think it still useful. I actually want to have a simple way to simulate the condition when multiple processes are accessing my disk and try to reproduce some bug.

Comment: sure. But I am interested in the part that haven't touch disk yet. There are lots of things, like you said, happen at file system, kernel, os level, which can affect the performance or introduce bug. In our experience different settings can result in very different behaviour, including multi-processes access same file system. I am trying to test reduced cases on our real data before defining fio tests.

Comment: ok, if you are not actually interested in multi-concurrent IO, I'll remove my comments to clean up your thread. good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You are facing a race-condition between the creation of the directories and the copying of the files.

What I did in my simple backup-script is:

- first create all the directories that is typically very quickly done
- then start copying. Because all the directories are already created, there will be no race condition anymore.