# How to copy files and folders in clipboard to all connected removable drives?

Tags: usb-flash-drive, automation, copy-paste, xcopy

I am a teacher. Usually, at the end of my classes, I want to share some files and folders in my computer (Windows 8) with my students. I have bought a USB hub that supports 4 parallel usb drives. However, I must copy the clipboard for each student, one by one (I usually forget about to which one the files are copied, so I have to resend them :(  ). I am seeking a solution that can send my clipboard to all connected removable drives (, and if possible, send them to a new folder).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm unclear why you say that you have to copy from the clipboard, it sounds like you just have to copy some files from source folder A to target folders B,C,D,E,...  In that case, some suggestions are here: http://superuser.com/questions/32630/parallel-file-copy-from-single-source-to-multiple-targets

Comment: No, I want to send it to all available USB flash drives (maybe 2 or 4 or even 0), not to some folders. BTW, that question is not answered yet, I hope someone can help me.

Comment: A drive **is** a folder, just the root one.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I found n2ncopy from the sourceforge. However, I have to set correct number of destinations (i.e., removable medias). The is a useful tool for me!