# Copying folder to multiple destinations in parallel

Tags: mac, terminal, file-transfer

I have to transfer roughly 250gb of data from a Master Drive to lots of USB drives, all of identical size and brand. When I copy using the GUI in Mac OSX, it waits to copy all the files to one drive and then copies the same files to drive 2.

Is there a way to copy the files across so that each file/bit is only read once and then written multiple times? This would presumably be faster than reading the same data over and over again. I have seen this question asked before, but I couldn't understand how the terminal commands worked.

Just so you know, I have very little experience with terminal, so if anyone has any great code, could they please explain how I would adjust it work with for me?

Many thanks

James

Comment: If you have any programming experience then you could simply write a program for it. It's not that hard.

Comment: Note that the OS *should* cache the data that is read, so it's still only actually *read* once. Whether the I/O scheduler is smart enough to parallelize the writes is another matter; I don't think this is a common enough scenario to optimize for.

Comment: @user I have the exact same problem as the Asker, your comment simplified my approach a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I know little about Mac OSX, still I believe its standard tools are similar to ones in Linux.

If it was for Linux/Bash I would try:

```
tar -c /source/dirA/ /source/file1 | tee >(cd /foo/destination3/ && tar -x) >(cd /bar/destination2/ && tar -x) >(cd /foobar/destination1/ && tar -x) > /dev/null
```

Every destination will receive `dirA/` and `file1`. You may give more arguments to the first `tar` (directories or files). In order to add another destination simply put additional `tee` argument in similar manner.

How does it work? First `tar` converts directories and files to a single bitstream that can be used in a pipe. The `tee` command forks that stream; every copy but one is extracted by `tar` in proper destination. The last copy moves down the pipe; it is discarded into `/dev/null`. (One may use the last copy for `destination0` but the syntax would be different so I decided to keep it simple with `tee` only).

The code is a starting point. You may need to adjust it to work with OSX.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, sounds like an excellent solution, I happen to have found a rather simple GUI based solution but much appreciated

Comment: You’re right; this does “make sense.”  (+1 for paying it forward.)

Answer (score 0):

After a little head scratching, my boss reminded me that the free software Davinci Resolve (a colour  grading application) now has some data wrangling facilities included. This allows you to select a source folder, multiple destinations and then it will copy each file simultaneously to each drive with one read and multiple writes.

I confirmed this through activity monitor which showed the data written per second to be three times greater than the read, and I was writing to three drives

https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/uk/products/davinciresolve